# Declaring a function with multiple variables in Assembly. (General Assembly Questions)

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, att, calling-convention

Im new to Assembly, so if some of these seem basic please bear with me. I have looked around many places but haven't found super relative answers to what I am asking. Im writing some assembly code and I need to write a function that takes in multiple variables and declares a single local variable. (Code below) I also would like to know where these variables are placed and how to access them in the function. Im quite experienced with languages (C, C++, java, Python, Swift) however assembly is quite different from anything else I've learned.

I have found some sources that simple say I need to use functions such as "function(int, int, int, int):" However looking at the compiled assembly code from gcc -S I don't see any functions declared like this. Below is an example of code I would like to emulate,

int func(int w, int x, int y, int z){

int a = 89;

return a;

}

Obviously this C code is quite worthless and doesn't use any of the passed variables. I was just using this as an example. However any information on how variables are passed, how functions are declared and how to access them (the variables) would be quite helpful. I understand where this code would be placed in terms of sections, but would like some information on questions stated above.

Comment: You are basically asking for an assembly tutorial.  This is a bit much for the scope of a Stack Overflow question.  Consider reading a book or tutorial instead.

Comment: In asm it's up to you to implement the calling convention.  It's not part of the language; you don't "declare" it except via comments.

Comment: assembly does not have functions just labels which is still a language abstract, but the closest you will get.   create a label that is your entry point, you define the calling convention (how and where parameters are passed in and results out) and then simply code it.